# showing data after clicking links(anchor tag) in a specific website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there any way to show the data i.e, when user starts accessing our website, after changing the two or three links of same website a data should be showed from the bottom.Is there any way to display the div when user changes the two or three links of my website.Below is my code

```js
 $(document).scroll(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var y = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (y > 800) {
            $('.fadein-data').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('#close-data').click(function() {
                $('.fadein-data').fadeOut();
                $(document).unbind('scroll');

            })

        }
    });
```

```css
.fadein-data {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    width: 350px;
    left: 20px;
    bottom: 0;
    border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    border-bottom: 0;
    padding: 30px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    z-index: 1050;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    box-shadow: 0 0.085em 0.5em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.165);
}
#close-data {
    float: right;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #000;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
    opacity: .2;
    top: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 9px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="fadein-data">
                <a type="button " id="close-data "><span aria-hidden="true ">×</span></a>
                <h4 class="mt-0 mb-10 ">Heading</h4>
                <p><b>The all in one software and some content</b></h4>

                    <img src="images/brochure.png ">
                    <br>
                    <a type="button " href="Brochure.pdf " class="btn btn-success">Download Brouchure</a>
            </div>
```

:

Comment: What is meant by `after changing the two or three links of same website`?

Comment: if user access my website and showing interest of accessing my website then only i want to show the hidden div

Answer (score 0):

So you want to start displaying your data once the user has already navigated through a few links? Here's one solution.
You can bind a callback to the

```
`$(window).on('hashchange', function(e){
// do something...
});`
```

event or the 
    `(document).location().change` 
event.

In the callback push the current url into a globally defined array and then check on the array length. If it's greater than 2 or 3 as per your need fire the callback to display your data. Here's a close example!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var navigatedUrls = [];
$(window).bind( 'hashchange', function(e) { 
    var anchor = document.location.hash;
    navigatedUrls.push(anchor);
    if(navigateUrls.length >2) {
        //call the method that displays data
    } 
});
});
```

You can replace the hash and location part based on how your Url is.
Here is a list of browsers that support `hashchange` event.
http://caniuse.com/#feat=hashchange